# how to show selected value from one page which contain whole database to another page using anchor in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show single persons details in new page using anchor link, but not able to do this, on click of "view all details" its show next page but can not show the single persons all details.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("dbs", $con) or die("ERROR");

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE fname like '%".$name."%' OR email like '%".$email."%'"  ;
    $q=mysql_query($sql);
}
else{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM user";
    $q=mysql_query($sql);
}
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>view all details</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $res['fname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['email'];?></td>
        <td><a href="view.php/<?php echo $res['fname'].'/'.$res['email']; ?>">view all details</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>

</table>
```

Comment: I'm not understanding one thing. This PHP script is the view.php or that anchor is pointing to somewhere else?

Comment: don't stuck in programming just solve my doubt, user seeing all customers  name, mail id in this page but she want to see the one persons details in view.php then how do i show details of one persons..  hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

For what I am understanding you want to see the person's details on another page and for that you need the name and the email. If that's the case, then you are building your URL wrongly. What you want is something like this:

```
<a href="view.php?name=<?= echo $res['fname'] ?>&email=<?= $res['email'] ?>">view all details</a>
```

This will output an URL that looks something like this `view.php?name=Andre&email=example`. Then inside your view.php script you obtain these values by using `$_GET['name']` and `$_GET['email']` and do the required operations with those.

Comment: now my doubt is how this line can check with my database, whether the selected values are correct or not...can you please suggest me.

Comment: Now you just have to query your database with the values from those two variables. And what do you mean if they are correct or not? It's as simple as taking those two values, query the DB and evaluate the returned rows.